# How to make jetty server (ring.adapter.jetty) accessible from external hosts

Tags: clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty, compojure, ring

I'm trying to run a web server using the following invocation

(run-jetty #'handler {:host "hostname" :port 8080})

This starts a server which I can access from the same host, but not externally. I am doing this on an EC2 instance and I use the internal IP of that machine as the "hostname", port 8080 is open for external access. I also tried using "0.0.0.0" as the hostname, but that resulted in the same behavior.

I'm using a slightly outdated version of ring-jetty-adapter (0.2.5) but I can't change that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies guys, it turns out that it was not a problem with jetty, I was running this on EC2, and had been applying port access permissions to a different security group than the one this particular instance belonged to :)

Answer (score 2):

to get access and keep it private you can run

ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 your.ec2.instance

then open a browser to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`

for your original question:
  perhaps using the external ip or host name as "hostname" may help?

Comment: thanks, using an ssh tunnel is a good idea, but in this case it doesn't work for me because I can't expect everyone who wants to use this web server to first create a tunnel.

Comment: yea, it's just a hack for access to the code while you are developing it without yet making it public. hopefully a helpful hint if not really an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Just don't specify the `:host` option at all; Jetty seems to listen on all interfaces in that case. For example, I help with [4clojure](http://4clojure.com). The webserver there is really running on port 8080 of the server raynes.me, with some nginx magic to forward port 80 if the host HTTP requests is 4clojure.com. You can access it directly if you like: http://raynes.me:8080 works fine, and here's our jetty call:

```
(run-jetty (var app) {:join? false :port 8080})
```

Comment: thanks, out of curiosity, how many users are using 4clojure now?